# Why can't Celery daemon see tasks?

Tags: debian, django, celery

I have a Django 1.62 application running on Debian 7.8 with Nginx 1.2.1 as my proxy server and Gunicorn 19.1.1 as my application server.  I've installed Celery 3.1.7 and RabbitMQ 2.8.4 to handle asynchronous tasks.  I'm able to start a Celery worker as a daemon but whenever I try to run the test "add" task as shown in the Celery docs, I get the following error:

```
Received unregistred task of type u'apps.photos.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/swing/venv/swing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: u'apps.photos.tasks.add'
```

If I start Celery from the command line, I can run the "add" task from within a Python interpreter console without a problem.

All of my configuration files are kept in a "conf" directory that sits just below my "myproj" project directory.  The "add" task is in apps/photos/tasks.py.

```
myproj
│
├── apps
    ├── photos
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── tasks.py
    conf
    ├── celeryconfig.py
    ├── celeryconfig.pyc
    ├── celery.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── middleware.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── dev.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── prod.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
```

Here is the tasks file:

```
# apps/photos/tasks.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from conf.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Here are my Celery application and configuration files:

```
# conf/celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from conf import celeryconfig

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'conf.settings')
app = Celery('conf')
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

# conf/celeryconfig.py
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', ]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

This is my Celery daemon config file.  I commented out CELERY_APP because I've found that the Celery daemon won't even start if I uncomment it.  I also found that I need to add the "--config" argument to CELERYD_OPTS in order for the daemon to start.  I created a non-privileged "celery" user who can write to the log and pid files.

```
# /etc/default/celeryd
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"
CELERY_BIN="/home/myproj/venv/myproj/bin/celery"
#CELERY_APP="conf"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/www/myproj/"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8 --config=celeryconfig"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

I can see from the log file that when I run the command, "sudo service celeryd start", Celery starts without any errors.  However, if I open the Python shell and run the following commands, I'll see the error I described at the beginning.

```
$ python shell
In [] from apps.photos.tasks import add
In [] result = add.delay(2, 2)
```

result.info is empty.  What's interesting is that if I examine Celery's registered tasks object, the task is listed:

```
In [] import celery
In [] celery.registry.tasks

Out [] {'celery.chain': ..., 'apps.photos.tasks.add': <@task: apps.photos.tasks.add of conf:0x16454d0> ...}
```

Other similar questions here have discussed having a PYTHONPATH environment variable and I don't have such a variable.  I've never understood how to set PYTHONPATH and this project has been running just fine for over a year without it.

I should also add that my production settings file is conf/settings/prod.py.  It imports all of my base (tier-independent) settings from base.py and adds some extra production-dependent settings.

I've also noticed that if I use a loglevel of "INFO" in my celeryd daemon file, I don't see any registered tasks in the Celery logfile.  I think you're supposed to see all registered tasks if you set loglevel to INFO.  I've confirmed this by running the celery command from the command line.  When I do that, I see my task as well as Celery's tasks within a [tasks] block.  However, when I start Celery using my celeryd init script, I don't see the [tasks] block at all. I don't even see Celery's built-in tasks such as celery.chain or celery.chord.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I've been struggling with this problem for two days and I'm out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I put a lot of effort into describing the problem and what I did to try to solve it so that others could learn from my efforts.  If you're going to down-vote me, you should at least provide a reason.

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? I am having the same issues

Comment: @Mikael I did manage to get it working but I'm at a loss to explain how I did it. Celery is very bad in that if it won't start, it often won't tell you why. Many times it is a matter of a log or pid file having incorrect permissions or ownership. I also switched from init.d to supervisor to get it working.  What I also found was that I needed to declare all my environment variables in supervisor.conf via its "environment" directive.  I hope this helps a little.  Good luck!

Comment: @Mikael, if you'd like to put your email in your profile, I'd be happy to send you a copy of my supervisor.conf, celeryapp.py, and celeryconfig.py files.  They may help you.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I managed to get it working myself. I had an error in my daemon config file + there were some permissions issues. All good now :)

Comment: @Mikael  I'm glad to hear it.  If anyone else reading this post is having problems, feel free to leave me a note here.  I'd like to help others avoid all the frustrations I encountered getting Celery to work.